# How to validate that a string is not equal to another (blacklist) with Joi?

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

A classical example is:

```
schema = Joi.object().keys({
    my_string: Joi.string().valid("myString").required()
});
```

This validate that object have field `my_string` which must have a `myString` as value.

How check that key  `my_string` is **not** equal to `notAllowedString`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can use **invalid**  to blacklist a value   ([link for ref](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v15.0.0/API.md#anyinvalidvalue---aliases-disallow-not))

```
schema = Joi.object().keys({
    my_string: Joi.string().invalid("notAllowedString").required()
});
```

Here's a full example of how you would use it:

```
const Joi = require('joi');

const schema = Joi.object({
  someIntA: Joi.number().integer().min(0).required(),
  someIntB: Joi.number()
    .integer()
    .min(0)
    .invalid(Joi.ref('someIntA'))
    .required(),
  someStringA: Joi.string().alphanum().min(3).max(30).required(),
  someStringB: Joi.string()
    .alphanum()
    .min(3)
    .max(30)
    .invalid(Joi.ref('someStringA'))
    .required(),
});
```